# bison++ vs bison - should they really conflict?

Tags: package-management, bison

I'm using Devuan Beowulf (i.e. Debian Buster without systemd).

I'm trying to build an application which requires bison++ (probably to generate C++ code). Now, bison++ is available, but - it conflicts with bison itself and bison is a much newer version (3.3.2 IIANM), while bisonc++ depends on a much older version (1.19).

So, I really want to have both... right? Or maybe it doesn't really matter? Why do these packages conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages conflict because they both ship `/usr/bin/bison`. I don’t know whether that’s sensible nowadays given how old `bison++` is.

I suspect you’ll need to switch between the packages depending on what you need to build. In the long run it might be worth porting the application to Bison, which supports C++ and is actively maintained.